# Sending text via TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcp

I am trying to create an application to send text via C# via TCP/IP.

When I compile the code I get no errors but when I press the button "Start" I get this exception:

**unhandled exception**:

> System.FormatException: 'The format of the input string is incorrect.'

**Code:**

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txthost.Text));
```

**Button code:**

```
private void btstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtstatus.Text += "server starting....";
    System.Net.IPAddress ip = new 
        System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txthost.Text));
    servr.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text));
}
```

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: is the IPAddress is in the correct format ?

Comment: WHat's the value of txthost.Text ?

Comment: What's the value of `txthost.Text` when the exception is thrown?  Why do you expect that value to be parsed to a `long`?

Comment: what is in txthost.Text? If it is 192.168.1.1 I don't expect long.Parse to succeed. Did you mean to use [`IPAddress.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes I meant that and it worked thanx "  System.Net.IPAddress ip =  System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txthost.Text);" the value of txthost.Text is 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 4):

You don´t need to convert the `string` to `long`. You can directly parse the `string` to `IPAddress` using
`System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(txtHost.Text);`

See the documentation for more information:
[IPAddress.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)
[IPAddress.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT:
You can also validate the input using the `TryParse()` method:

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip;
bool isValid = System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(txtHost.Text, out ip);
```

If the parsed IPAddress is not valid you can show a Dialogue that the user should enter a valid IP.